# Exiting from gnuplot using Python?

Tags: python, gnuplot

I have the code below to run Xyce (simulating platform) to simulate my netlist and then plot the output csv file using gnuplot. It works fine and plots the output file, however, my command window gets stuck in the gnuplot window. So my question is how to exit from gnuplot at this point in order to proceed with my code/script normally. I tried to call `exit` didn't work. I also tried to run gnuplot in the background but didn't have any luck. And finally I tried the command `terminate()` but also no luck. So, can anybody help?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Plotting Output File

import subprocess
import Gnuplot

subprocess.call(['./Xyce','mscmemory_cell.cir'])
g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot()
g.plot(Gnuplot.File('mscmemory_cell.cir.prn', using=(2,3), with_="lines"))
subprocess.call('gnuplot')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that subprocess.call() is blocking, from the python documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

My question to you is: how do you know when you want the program to continue normally?

If you merely want to launch gnuplot via the shell and keep your main program chugging along, you're digging in the right Python module, wrong function as subprocess.call() will block execution until the command completes.  I would look at Popen.

That being said, I'm a little confused as to why subprocess.call('gunuplot') is necessary.  From the package's demo.py, it looks like calling Gnuplot.Gnuplot() should have started an instance of the program.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Answering the first question, How would I know I want to continue normally? this will depend on ht results itself. So for example I going to simulate, plot at a certain step value then next is simulate, plot at another step value and so on.

Regarding the subprocess.call() I have to add it at the end of the code like that or nothing will be plotted. So do you have a solution on how to use it without using subprocess.call()

Comment: As far as whether or not you want the program to continue, the answer is probably "yes," as it sounds like you want to keep running the simulation in a loop until your plot meets visual requirements.  I suggest looking at raw_input() if you want to give room in your code for manual intervention.  For the second part, have you tried running "demo.py" included in the package to see if it works?  ( http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/ ) If it does, try to figure out what might be different with your code.